# Git: why do I have to commit other people's changes

Tags: git, svn, github

I suppose many people who are more used to SVN than to Git are confused with this, so maybe someone can clarify.

I commit and push some changes to Git repository. I do nothing for some time. Meanwhile other people commit and push their changes. Then I try to pull their changes and I can't do that because `git status` shows that I have to commit some changes which are not mine. What does it mean? What happens when I commit those changes? What kind of commit message should I use for this kind of 'commit'?

Obviously Git concept of 'commit' is very different from SVN's, to which I am used to, where you simply `update` to get other people's changes, and commit only your own changes.

Comment: I don't see how this situation can happen. Could you post the exact message you get when pulling?

Comment: It says: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
... (list of files changed not by me but by other people) ...
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting

Comment: Are you doing `git checkout <commit-id> <filenames>`, e.g., `git checkout HEAD~5 foo.c` for instance, to look at older versions of specific files?

Comment: If I try git checkout using id of last commit I see in repository, I get the same error message.

Comment: @cincplug: that's why I said *of specific files*: `git checkout <commit-id>` is very different from `git checkout <commit-id> <file>`.  The former is concerned about overwriting and errors out, but the latter assumes you *want* to replace the file with someone else's version, and does so.

Comment: Ok, so I did `git checkout <id> *` and now it is clean. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear where you're going wrong (you have not given us enough information) but I should point out two things here:

1. Your git repository and working directory are just that: *yours*.  Any changes are changes *you* asked for.  You may simply not have realized (especially if you start using some of the more obscure features of git) that you asked for them.

   Of course, this is true of SVN as well, but that brings me to...
2. While both git and svn *can* give you a "whole repository" view, svn encourages—or at least, does not actively discourage—a "one file at a time" mode of operation.  This is possible in git (to some extent) but it is not a good idea as you will be working against git's general thrust, which is that "all of the repository at once" view.

It sounds as though you got yourself in trouble by asking git to check out an older commit, but not the *entire* older commit:

```
$ git checkout master@{1.week.ago}
```

This would get you the entire repository (into your working directory) as of one week ago, at which point you can inspect individual files as desired.<sup>1</sup>  But if you just wanted to look at one specific file, say, `foo.txt`, you might be tempted to do this instead:

```
$ git checkout master@{1.week.ago} foo.txt
```

I won't say "never do this", but if and when you *do* do this, be very careful: you're telling git "I intend to change foo.txt in the *next* commit to match the way it was 1 week ago."

Specifically, git has the "index" (AKA "staging area") in which you build each "next commit": you modify some file(s), add them to the index/stage, and when you're satisfied with the staged arrangement, you run `git commit` to turn that arrangement into a new, complete commit.

When you use the specific-file(s) form of `git checkout` (`git checkout [rev] path ...`), this tells git to extract the old versions of the file and *write them into the index* as well as into the working-tree.  In other words, you're asking git to get the old version of the file, put it in your work-tree, *and* `git add` the result.

To get out of this situation, use `git reset --hard` (be very careful with this command as well as it re-sets, i.e., wipes out changes in, both your index and your work-tree), or `git checkout` the most recent version of the file(s) you clobbered by checking out older versions, to put things back the way they were.

---

<sup>1</sup>More specifically, this form of `git checkout` leaves you with a "detached HEAD": it checks out a specific commit by finding its commit-ID.  This first makes sure it won't overwrite any existing work, then sets your index and work-tree to match the selected commit, and also updates `HEAD` to hold that commit-ID.  If, later, you `git checkout master`, git can tell that you have made no changes from that specific commit-ID, and safely put you back "on branch master" as `git status` will show.  So this form of checkout-old / restore-current is "safer" in that you don't have to make sure you are not going to lose any work; git will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I think I now understand better how it works.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you did a merge resulting in conflicts previously and you forgot to conclude it with a commit.

Then, `git status` will tell you about the uncommitted changes that you have in your tree, and they include changes that you brought by merging. Recent enough versions of Git should tell you something like

```
$ git status
[...]
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
```